# How to display an sticky element above an image?

Tags: html, css

I am making a website and i have an **"sticky element"** and a bunch of images below, the thing is, if i scroll down the **"sticky element"** goes ***behind*** the image and therefore, becomes invisible. I want to make the **"sticky element"** visible when i scroll down. I have tried the *"z-index"* CSS property but it doesn't works (maybe i'm not using it correctly).

```
<style>
div{
  position: sticky;
}
</style>

<body>
 <div>
  "Sticky element"
 </div>
<br>
 <img src="https://www.cecidiomas.es/images/cecidiomases/684-thinking-of-getting-a-cat-international-cat-care-3435.png">
<br>
 <img src="https://www.cecidiomas.es/images/cecidiomases/684-thinking-of-getting-a-cat-international-cat-care-3435.png">
</body>
```

Comment: Increase z-index value and add !important at the end like this ```z-index:9999 !important;``` try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see, you don't need z-index to achieve this, maybe you forgot to add top to your sticky element? I also added a pink background to the element so that it's easier visible but that's not required of course

You only need z-index if elements that come after also have a z-index defined.

```css
#sticky{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="sticky">
  "Sticky element"
 </div>
<br>
 <img src="https://www.cecidiomas.es/images/cecidiomases/684-thinking-of-getting-a-cat-international-cat-care-3435.png">
<br>
 <img src="https://www.cecidiomas.es/images/cecidiomases/684-thinking-of-getting-a-cat-international-cat-care-3435.png">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also try this if it helps you, bcz you didn't mentioned why u wanna use sticky. So this solution works exactly same like u wanted.

```
<style>
div{
  position: fixed;
  background-color: beige;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
</style>

<body>
 <div>
  "Sticky element"
 </div>
<br>
 <img src="https://www.cecidiomas.es/images/cecidiomases/684-thinking-of-getting-a-cat-international-cat-care-3435.png">
<br>
 <img src="https://www.cecidiomas.es/images/cecidiomases/684-thinking-of-getting-a-cat-international-cat-care-3435.png">
</body>
```